# R/SQL: Using the April Calendar Year instead of January Calendar Year?

Tags: sql, r

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have a table (my_table) that looks like this (date is in year-month-date format):

```
     my_date color
1 2020/12/18   red
2 2021/12/18 green
3 2022/12/18  blue
```

**My Question:** I am trying to write an SQL statement that looks at a "April to April year" instead of "January to January year". For example, an input of 2020/12/18 should return 2020/2021.

I know how to solve this problem using the R programming language:

```
library(lubridate)

# function
get_april_to_april_year <- function(date) {
  year <- year(date)
  month <- month(date)
  
  if(month >= 4) { 
    return(paste0(year, "/", year + 1))
  } else {
    return(paste0(year - 1, "/", year))
  }
}

date <- ymd("2020/05/17")
get_april_to_april_year(date)
```

**But can someone please show me how I can do this in SQL?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with SQLite and H2 and may work with your database.  I have changed the second row so we can test the both legs of the condition.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *, 
    case
      when substr(my_date, 6, 2) > '03' then 
             substr(my_date, 1, 5) || (substr(my_date, 1, 4) + 1)
      else (substr(my_date, 1, 4) - 1 )|| '/' || substr(my_date, 1, 4)
    end as fy 
  from DF")
##      my_date color        fy
## 1 2020/12/18   red 2020/2021
## 2 2021/02/18 green 2020/2021
## 3 2022/12/18  blue 2022/2023
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "my_date color
1 2020/12/18   red
2 2021/02/18 green
3 2022/12/18  blue"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```